# Вставка текста в массив текстбоксов - c#

Tags: c#, массивы, winforms, строки, textbox

Ситуация такая. Есть массив текстбоксов tb[] (на форме их много, допустим начиная с textBox1 по textBox36). Копирую текст из какого-нибудь текстового файла. Как сделать, чтобы по нажатию кнопки в каждый последующий текстбокс вставился текст из буфера обмена, но с небольшим условием. В каждый текстбокс начиная с первого должны вставиться каждые 6 строк из скопированного текста. Например, есть текст из 18 строк, в первый текстбокс должны вставиться строки с 1 по 6, во второй с 7 по 12, в третий с 13 по 18 ( и т. д.). Задачка может показаться странной, но мне это очень нужно ) . Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Это решается так:

```
textBoxes[i].Text = string.join("", fileLines.Skip(i).Take((i+1)*6));
```